# How to take data filtered by True or False

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have this code in Controller,, I need for report to take data where is just checked checkbox or value is true,

```
public ActionResult Report()
{
    var ponudis = db.ponudis.Include(s => s.ponudaDets)
        .Where (!ponudis.odobreno);
    return View(ponudis.ToList());
}
```

I need code like this, but now is problem filtering .Where.

How to corect this code and to take data from database where odobreno cell is true.

Answer (score 1):

Try with a lambda expression:

```
var ponudis = db.ponudis.Include(s => s.ponudaDets).Where(x => !x.odobreno);
```

This will select all items with `odobreno` field equal to `false`.